# Using the calc package to draw a polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a pentagon. The point `A_1` is at the origin, and the point `A_2` is at `(60:1.75)`, expressed in polar coordinates. I would like `A_3` to be 0.5cm from `A_2` and perpendicular to line segment `$\overline{A_1A_2}$`, `A_4` to be 1cm from `A_3` and rotated 120 degrees from line segment `$\overline{A_2A_3}$`, and `A_5` to be 0.75 cm from `A_4` and rotated 120 degrees from line segment `$\overline{A_3A_4}$`.  That is not what is drawn.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}



\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) coordinate (A_1)
(60:1.75) coordinate (A_2)
($(A_2) +($(A_2)!0.5cm!90:(A_1)$)$) coordinate (A_3)
($(A_3) +($(A_3)!1cm!120:(A_2)$)$) coordinate (A_4)
($(A_4) +($(A_4)!0.75cm!120:(A_3)$)$) coordinate (A_5);
\draw (A_1) -- (A_2) -- (A_3) -- (A_4) -- (A_5) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] (A_1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (A_2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (A_3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (A_4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (A_5) circle (1.5pt);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, less is more.  (I added the nodes just to see what was going on.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}



\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) coordinate (A_1)
(60:1.75) coordinate (A_2)
($(A_2)!0.5cm!90:(A_1)$) coordinate (A_3)
($(A_3)!1cm!120:(A_2)$) coordinate (A_4)
($(A_4)!0.75cm!120:(A_3)$) coordinate (A_5);

\draw (A_1) -- (A_2) -- (A_3) -- (A_4) -- (A_5) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] (A_1) circle (1.5pt) node[above] {A1};
\draw[fill] (A_2) circle (1.5pt) node[above] {A2};
\draw[fill] (A_3) circle (1.5pt) node[above] {A3};
\draw[fill] (A_4) circle (1.5pt) node[above] {A4};
\draw[fill] (A_5) circle (1.5pt) node[above] {A5};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pentagon]

Comment: I see that you removed the `(A_i) +` from the commands for coordinates of `A_3`, `A_4`, and `A_5`.  Why is my code wrong for locating these three points?  I thought that `\coordinate (A_3) at ($(A_2) +($(A_2)!0.5cm!90:(A_1)$)$)` places `A_3` at 0.5cm from `A_2` that is perpendicular to line segment `$\overline{A_1A_2}$`.

Comment: ($(A)!1cm!90:(B)$)  translates as "Start at (A) and travel 1cm in the direction 90 from (B)".

Comment: Start at `A` and travel 1cm in the direction 90 degrees from line segment `AB`.

Comment: @user74973 -  If we are using strict geometry nomenclature, make that 90 degrees counter-clockwise from $\overrightarrow{AB}$ ;-)

Comment: That will save me some time ... if I can remember it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short code from `pst-node`

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \psset{dimen=middle, unit=2, labelsep=0.8ex, linecolor=IndianRed3, linewidth=1.2pt}
    \pnode(0,0){A}
    \AplusB(A)(1.75;60){B}\AplusB(B)(.5;-30){C}\AplusB(C)(1;-90){D}\AplusB(D)(.75;-150){E}
    \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)(D)(E)
    \uput[l](A){$A$}\uput[u](B){$B$}\uput[ur](C){$C$}\uput[r](D){$D$}\uput[d](E){$E$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]